# Python - Speech Recognition time offsets

Tags: python, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I am trying to do speech recognition using python. In addition to this, I need to get the times of beginning and end of each word.

I would rather use a free library that can deal with this. I've heard that Sphinx is able to do this but I couldn't find any examples (for python anyway).

I would appreciate any help or suggestions.